# IndentationError in Google App Engine Sample

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Error (From Log Console):

```
File "D:\dev\gamerofprogrammer\guessbook\main.py", line 62
greeting = greetings_query.fetch(10)
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

My code

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.write('<html><body>')
    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name', DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)

    greetings_query = Greeting.query(ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(Greeting.date)      
    greeting = greetings_query.fetch(10)

    for greeting in greetings:
        if greeting.author:
            self.response.write('<b> </b> wrote: ' % greeting.author.nickname())
        else:
            self.response.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
        self.response.write('<blockquote> %s </blockquote>' % cgi.escape(greeting.content))

    if users.get_current_user():
        url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Logout'
    else:
        url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'logout'

    sign_query_params = urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name})
    self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_FOOTER_TEMPLATE % (sign_query_params, cgi.escape(GUESTBOOK_NAME), url, url_linktext))
```

all theses codes can be found in [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore?hl=pt-br)
What is the trouble with my Indentation ?

Comment: Try checking if you're mixing tabs and spaces in your code?

Comment: Try re indenting the code properly and consistently with just tabs or just spaces

Comment: the python cares about my 'enters' or a spaces between '='?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really mean to answer this, but the ability to format things in comments is limited here.  This is the **kind** of thing that produces `IndentationError`:

```
a = 1
 b = 2
```

The second (`b = 2`) line is indented one space more than the line before it.  Apparently your  `greeting = greetings_query.fetch(10)` line, in its source file, is similarly indented more than the line before it.

Beyond that, can't add more than the comments already said:  stick to all spaces, or to all tabs.

Ah, one more thing:  it's unlikely that your `greeting = greetings_query.fetch(10)` is indented **less** than the line before it.  **This** kind of thing:

```
 a = 1
b = 2
```

produces a different detail message:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

That's not the one you're getting.